# C# compiler: CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#

This is the craziest what I've seen since a Fody plugin ruined my assembly by emitting invalid code and control flow varied random at runtime... No Fody this time.

Facts:

- The whole story is within one project.
- The GetMessage extension method is there since weeks...
- The issue is started since 2 hours, and I can not figure out what it is.
- There is only one GetMessage extension method.
- The error message (see the pic) lists two *identical* method specification

  `Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ComiCalc.Data.ExceptionExtensions.GetMessage2(System.Exception)' and 'ComiCalc.Data.ExceptionExtensions.GetMessage2(System.Exception)' ComiCalc.Data D:\2014Develop\.vsonline\ComiCalc\src\ComiCalc.Data\Services\UserService.cs    61`
- If I change both the call, both the method definition (only 2 edits in 2 places) to GetMessage2, then I got exactly the same error message just referring to the GetMessage2.
- Using VS 2015

Any ideas?

[image]

and here is the single one method:

```
namespace ComiCalc.Data
{

    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
    using PluralTouch.DataAccess;
    // TODO: Move to PluralTouch
    public static class ExceptionExtensions
    {
        public static string GetMessage2(this Exception exception)
        {

            var message = exception.Message;
            if (exception is DbEntityValidationException)
            {
                message = ((DbEntityValidationException) exception).DbEntityValidationResultToString();
            }
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you post screenshots of code? Get the actual code in there, please.

Comment: Is this a web application?

Comment: @Jashaszun:In case you care about  read the problem, you will recognize this question is not about the code instead the IDE and/or the compiler. I've spent 1+ hours to figure out what is going on, and spent 15+ mins to describe all I am experiencing, and the screenshots are there to give you the closest experience I am seeing. Anyway thanks for  the 3 minuses for those who click without reading

Comment: Try rebuilding entire project.  Normally I delete the bin folder to force all code to recompile.  I suspect a library change in your compiled code that may be using a different library or older version of the library.

Comment: @g.pickardou If you're showing things that are better shown with images (e.g. build settings), then screenshots are fine. Code and error messages, however, are invariably better communicated through text.

Comment: And again: See the right answer: It proves my question had _all_  diagnostic information in its initial version to diagnose what's going on and that issue was not about the code

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure you don't reference the output binary in your project references (i.e., the project references itself). This has happened to me in the past with Resharper (the addition of the output binary to the project references), so the extension method is both in the source and in the binary reference.

Comment: Thanks man. I've never figured out this. I got some feeling that there is some not updated reference could be done this trick, so I've cleaned up all, but after seeing the problem is within the very same assembly, I rejected this hypothesis. And also yes, that was Resharper.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I also had the problem in the same assembly and was using resharper. The resharper optimise usings fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Delete bin folder > open project > build solution.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error because my project referenced to a dll, and at the same time had a  transitive dependency to the same dll but at different file path.

Spotted it using extra logging during the build (Tools -> Options -> Build and Run ->output verbosity to Detailed or Diagnostic) by searching for dependency dll name: in Task "Csc" there were two occurrences of /reference with the dll

Fix was to point references to the same dll path

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Resharper had created a new file named `Annotations1.cs` file. I just deleted it and the problem solved. Maybe you need delete debug / release / obj and clean / rebuild solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and moved all files except **'bin', 'references', 'obj'** and boom. It works like charm..

Answer (score 0):

I had two exact classes created by a DB tool, because was executed 2 times with different parameters. I search by the class name and remove the newer, after that everything goes OK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the "publish" folder within my project folder. Removing the "publish" folder solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I hit the same problem [impossible resolution conflicts between a single method and itself] because I used C# 8.0 and its shiny new features to build three projects that depend upon each other, transitively, like this:

- Project C depends on project B.
- Project B depends on project A.
- Project C calls APIs from types in project B that inherit types from project A. Some of those APIs have nullable reference type parameters.

Also, I had **nullability checking** enabled *only* for project A, and completely disabled for projects B and C.

The fix for me was to enable nullable *annotations* in project B (I did this without also enabling warnings).

I speculate that this fixes the problem by ensuring there weren't two completely different compiler modes (nullable annotated on/off) reprocessing the same interface definition, while building two projects (A and B), and then up putting conflicting nullability annotations on their respective outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while migrating from .NET3.1 to .NET6.0. I got my issue fixed by updating the reference package "System.Interactive" to the latest version (6.0.1 in my case) in csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when using Shared Projects in Visual Studio.
My shared project was included as a reference by project A. Project B then referenced project A.
I mistakenly added the shared project to project B, leading to two instances of each of the shared files in the project.
I then saw this error for a string extension method in one of the shared files where it was called from another shared file.

Answer (score -2):

In my case I just have add "path" to the code!!! hope that helps error CS0121