# Ambiguous use of System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, httpclient

Could you please help me to know why this error appear ??

> error:Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.SetBearerToken(System.Net.Http.HttpClient, string)' and 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.SetBearerToken(System.Net.Http.HttpClient, string)'  ImportTrustsApp C:\@Noha Basiony\NowInfinity Web\web\smsf.web\ImportTrustsApp\Program.cs    45  Active

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729186/c-sharp-compiler-cs0121-the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or) question might be helpful if you happen to be using ReSharper.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that older versions of **`System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions`**
assemblies have been cached and now they conflict with the newly installed assemblies. Please follow these steps, which should help you overcome the problem:

1. Delete your current **`System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions`** reference.
2. Add new **`System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions`** reference.
3. Close Visual Studio .
4. Clear the project's Bin and Obj folders.
5. Rebuild your application.

Comment: @Noha Basiony,I hope this is useful ?